# C# passing list from json to the viev, and showing in one textbox

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view

in my code I want return in Json list with three dates.

Something similar to this:

```
DateTime? localDate = DateTime.Now;
        
        
        DateTime?[] dateTimes = new DateTime?[]
        {
            localDate,
            localDate,
            localDate
        };

        return Json(dateTimes);
```

I would like to show this data in my view in on textbox, great if this dates was separeted by comma.
I know how do this in only c# and pass only one string but i have too much code.
Maybe is another, better way to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change/avoid explicit array declaration with localDate repeating 3 times ?

Comment: Now, i have array with three values, which i returned by Json.
After that, i wanna show this all values from my list on my textbox on my page.

Comment: So you want to take the array of dates, put them into JSON format and then display the JSON text into your textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your `Json()` method is doing and why you aren't just using:

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject();`

But to get your array of 3 dates into Json string you just need to do:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateTimes, Formatting.Indented);
```

Which would result in the following string:

```
[
  "2021-09-27T10:11:11.7616692+00:00",
  "2021-09-27T10:11:11.7616692+00:00",
  "2021-09-27T10:11:11.7616692+00:00"
]
```

Alternatively...

If you want to just put the 3 dates into a string separated by a comma, you can do:

```
var datesString = string.Empty;

dateTimes.ToList().ForEach(date => {
datesString += $"{date},";
});

dateString = dateString.Remove(dateString.LastIndexOf(","));
```

Which will result in something like: `9/27/2021 10:14:17 AM,9/27/2021 10:14:17 AM,9/27/2021 10:14:17 AM`

---

In term of `passing` this back to the view, you should use `Binding` on the Textbox, something like:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding DatesString, Mode=OneWay}/>
```

Then inside your ViewModel, change the value of the property `DatesString` to the result from the previous mentioned code.

With your `DatesString` property looking like this:

```
private string _datesString;

public string DatesString
{
   get => this._datesString;
   set => 
   {
       this._datesString = value;
       this.PropertyChanged(ref _datesString, value); //// Your NotifyPropertyChanged Event
   }
}
```